# Does anyone know which script would cause placeholder text to be removed from text inputs and put into spans?

Tags: javascript, html, input, placeholder

I have a page that I added to a project that was already underway, and when I added the masterpage, it was given a whole bunch of scripts. Among these scripts is something that is messing with the styles on my page.

There are several different bugs, but the two biggest things are

1. It moves my placeholder text into external spans, and these spans are all positioned wrong.
2. It is adding a `keypress` function to my searchbar that goes to the wrong place.

The thing is, it looks like I have about 20 scripts on the page thanks to the masterpage, so I don't know where to even start putting breakpoints.

Is there any simple way I can find out which scripts are responsible for doing these weird things? Does anyone know of a specific script that would cause that placeholder text issue?

Comment: Please re-read your question, and think carefully how anybody can answer it with the information you've shared.

Comment: I was simply asking if there is any known method for figuring out which scripts are causing behaviors on a page.

Comment: the simplest: remove the scripts one by one until the behavior disappears.

Comment: Then that is what you should ask instead @user3784238. it should be: "is there any way to trace DOM modification"? yes chrome has this feature in dev tools look here: http://www.qwiple.com/posts/5037/chrome-developer-tools-dom-breakpoints

Comment: chrome debugger offers a brakepoint on attribute modification. Have a look in this direction

Comment: I would personally remove scripts from the page one-by-one until the issue no longer is shown.  Then you know what file it's in.  From there, you can continue to remove code from that particular script until you narrow down the culprit.  Simple and basic debugging really, process of elimination.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't tried out the [break on dom attribute modification](http://www.qwiple.com/posts/5037/chrome-developer-tools-dom-breakpoints) in chrome dev tools or don't have chrome installed. or it might be an IE specific Then you could do it with plain javascript by monkey patching the setter method with [object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

If it is using `setAttribute("placeholder", "")` or `removeAttribute("placeholder")` try monkey patching that one instead.

here is an example:

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('input');

// change the setter method
Object.defineProperty(target, 'placeholder', {
  set: function(newValue) {
    // log the code that made the change
    throw (new Error()).stack;
  }
});

function updateDom() {
  changeInput();
}

function changeInput() {
  target.placeholder = ""
}

setTimeout(updateDom, 100);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="foo">
```

if that doesn't help cuz it's a deep minified jQuery hook that doesn't trace back to your code, than you only choice is to "cut and trace"